# EasyImage Yii undefined method Image::factory()

Tags: methods, yii, undefined, crop

I downloaded the EasyImage extension for Yii to crop images but whenever i want to init the image this fatal error comes up:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Image::factory() in C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\GitHub\askengine\protected\extensions\yii-easyimage\EasyImage.php on line 41
```

Cant figure out why.

My Controller:

```
Yii::import('ext.yii-easyimage.EasyImage');
$image = new EasyImage("avatar/".$fileName);
$image->crop($_POST['w'], $_POST['h'], $_POST['x1'], $_POST['y1']);
$image->save();
```

The EasyImage class _construct():

```
public function __construct($file = null, $driver = null)
{
    if ($file) {
        return $this->_image = Image::factory($this->detectPath($file), $driver ? $driver : $this->driver);
    }
}
```

And the Image.php :

```
public static function factory($file, $driver = NULL)
{
    if ($driver === NULL) {
        // Use the default driver
        $driver = Image::$default_driver;
    }

    // Set the class name
    $class = 'Image_' . $driver;
    return new $class($file);
}
```

I tried to use directly the Image.php but it ended with failure:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Image::factory() in C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\GitHub\askengine\protected\controllers\ImageController.php on line 60
```

Comment: I figured out why. I have an ActiveRecord Image.

Comment: You need Image::factory(); or EasyImage::factory(); ?